# Find functions creating garbage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing a game and it sometimes gets a little choppy. I'm pretty sure this is when the garbage is collected. It seems to be worse with the new chrome version (50). As far as I know, there is no way for me to force garbage collection, so that I could prevent build up and release in one go.

So now I am trying to find out, where the data that will be garbage collected is created. I am already using pooling for all my game objects.

Is there a way to find the functions generating the garbage?

Comment: You can force garbage collection of an object by removing all references to said object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Chrome Dev Tools' "Profiles -> Record Heap Allocations" is what You are looking for.

[image]

Google has a thorough description on how one could [debug a web app for memory problems](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/memory-diagnosis), You definitely should check it out.